# Hide, load, and show div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hide

I have a few pages from each other to interact with page with id load, as below:

inside process.html

```
<div id="guest_details"> </div>

<div id="first_start"> </div>
<script>
<! -
$('#guest_details').load('?p=guest_details.html');
$('#first_start').load('?p=first_start.html')
$('#guest_details').hide('slow');
$('#first_start').SlideUp('slow')
->
</Script>
```

inside guest_details.html

```
<form action="guest_details.php" <form method="POST" id="guest">
<!-- Some cell here -->
<a onclick="$('#guest').submit();" class="button" id="first_start"> <span> <?php echo $button_submit;?> </span> </a>
</Form>
```

That I want is when the submit button is clicked then:

1. data sent to guest_details.php
2. If the data has been sent then hide **< div id="guest_details"> < /div>**
3. showing the show **< div id="first_start"> < /div>**

but when I make it like the above, that not work, Could someone give a clue how to correct?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you even posting the form using AJAX?

Comment: btw: `.SlideUp('slow')` should be `.slideUp('slow')`

Comment: your html fails, a form within the form tag :P. Validate your code some time.

Comment: **@ sandeepan**, Yes I use AJAX/Jquery but unfortunetelly I am very new to it. **@Sebastian Patane Masuelli**, I am sorry, it only mistype it should be .slideUp('slow') or .show('slow'). **@ Mark Baijens**, again it only mistype at here, but I very Appreciate all of pointers from You Guys, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your previous question and your tags, I assume you are not much aware of AJAX.

You need to

1.post the form asynchronously (without reloading the page, using AJAX).
2. On successfully sending the data, do the dom manipulations.

I suggest using jquery for doing an AJAX post.

Here is a sample code, using jquery:-

```
$('#guest_details').load('?p=guest_details.html');
$('#first_start').load('?p=first_start.html')

function ajaxPostForm()
{    
  $.post('guest_details.php', 

  function(data) {

    //Dom manipulation
    $('#guest_details').hide('slow');
    $('#first_start').SlideUp('slow')

  });

 }
```

And your form html inside `guest_details.html` needs to be like:-

```
<form method="POST" id="guest">
<!-- Some cell here -->
<a onclick="ajaxPostForm();" class="button" id="first_start"> <span> <?php echo $button_submit;?> </span> </a>
</Form>
```

The $.post given above is a very basic AJAX post. You may add further features as give in [Jquery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Also if you want to post the entire form, you can refer [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

**Updates**
I think I understood your problem better this time. Inside your update where you say this-

> by default guest_details.html is
>   showing and first_start.html is hiding

referring to the sections as `guest_details` and `first_start` would make more sense because `guest_details.html` may mean the page `guest_details.html` which you might have opened in another window.

Anyway, I am sure you mean the sections inside the page `process.html` as you have used jquery `.load()`. Let's call the `first_start.html` and `guest_details.html` as sections  `first_start` and `guest_details` respectively.

As per your updates do you mean the following:-

**Initial state**
Section `guest_details` is shown and `first_start` is hidden

**Cases/Situations**
When form inside `guest_details` section is submitted, then hide the section `guest_details` and show `first_start` section.

At this state when `guest_details` is hidden and `first_start` is shown, the button on `first_start` can be clicked and on doing so the `guest_details` section shows again.

During these states where one section is hidden and another is shown reloading/refreshing the page should preserve the states.

If above is the complete scenario, here is the code:-

```
<script>
<! -
initiateSections(<?php echo $this->session->data['display_state']; ?>);
//state can have "display_first_start" or "display_guest_details"
function initiateSections(state)
{
    $('#guest_details').load('?p=guest_details.html');
    $('#first_start').load('?p=first_start.html')


    if(state == "display_first_start")
    {
        displayFirstStart();
    }
    else
    {//If chosen or by default
        displayGuestDetails();
    }

}

function ajaxPostGuestDetails()
{    
  $.post('guest_details.php',  //In this post request - set $this->session->data['display_state'] = 'display_first_start'; in php

  function(data) 
  {
        //Dom manipulation
    displayFirstStart();
  });

}

function ajaxPostFirstStart()
{    
  $.post('first_start.php',  //In this post request - set  $this->session->data['display_state'] = 'display_guest_details'; 

  function(data) 
  {
    //Dom manipulation
        displayGuestDetails();
  });

}

function displayGuestDetails()
{
    $('#first_start').hide('slow');
    $('#guest_details').slideUp('slow');
}

function displayFirstStart()
{
    $('#guest_details').hide('slow');
    $('#first_start').slideUp('slow');
}
->
</Script>
```

Comment: Yeaah, You look gave some complete clue, I will try it first, and I will looking forward after getting the result, see You and Thanks

Comment: I've tried the code, but do not have good luck, the data from guest_details.html not sent, but after a button clicked at guest_details.html page then guest_details.html hidden and first_start.html not showing, I'd posted a more complete original code again, please have a look. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement ajax to post the data to php

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```

use ajax success to do your post success activities.

Once ajax is successful do the HTML manipulations

```
success: function(data) {

}
```

Comment: Hi gov, I completed my post, please have a see what is i missing, Thanks